# JSON Exception when trying to retrieve object string

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, openstreetmap

I'm trying to retrieve the "Maxspeed" string from the JSON below.
It iterates through the array, but when it reaches the "tag" object and tries to retrieve the "maxspeed" value, it returns an exception(below).

Would anyone know why this is happening? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for maxspeed
```

Java:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray speedJSON = parentObject.getJSONArray("elements"); 

                for (int i = 0; i < speedJSON.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject element = (JSONObject) speedJSON.get(i);

                    if (!element.isNull("tags")) {
                        //JSONObject tags = (JSONObject) speedJSON.getJSONObject(i).get("tags");
                        String maxspeed = element.getString("maxspeed");
                        txtSpeed.setText(maxspeed+" here");
                    } else {
                        //Your error handling here...
                    }
                }
                //txtSpeed.setText(""+);
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
```

JSON:

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2015-03-16T20:10:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 768053039,
  "lat": 54.9526671,
  "lon": -7.7273348
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 768053040,
  "lat": 54.9498094,
  "lon": -7.7176056
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 768053041,
  "lat": 54.9497066,
  "lon": -7.7173174
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 768053043,
  "lat": 54.9495658,
  "lon": -7.7170937
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 768053044,
  "lat": 54.9495035,
  "lon": -7.7169816
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 791492493,
  "lat": 54.9494183,
  "lon": -7.7168205
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 795319854,
  "lat": 54.9510427,
  "lon": -7.7218262
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 795320324,
  "lat": 54.9509153,
  "lon": -7.7213706
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1922546572,
  "lat": 54.9502165,
  "lon": -7.7190169
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1922546679,
  "lat": 54.9504739,
  "lon": -7.7199078
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1922546692,
  "lat": 54.9500860,
  "lon": -7.7185174
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1922602861,
  "lat": 54.9517250,
  "lon": -7.7241644
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1922622063,
  "lat": 54.9514357,
  "lon": -7.7231690
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 2673934802,
  "lat": 54.9498543,
  "lon": -7.7177617
},
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 64273241,
  "nodes": [
    768053039,
    1922602861,
    1922622063,
    795319854,
    795320324
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "secondary",
    "maxspeed": "60",
    "name": "Port Road",
    "oneway": "no",
    "ref": "R229"
  }
},
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 64887990,
  "nodes": [
    795320324,
    1922546679,
    1922546572,
    1922546692,
    2673934802,
    768053040,
    768053041,
    768053043,
    768053044,
    791492493
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "secondary",
    "maxspeed": "60",
    "name": "Port Road",
    "oneway": "no",
    "ref": "R229"
  }
}

  ]
}
```

Comment: Because the object you're trying to get the maxspeed value from doesn't have a maxspeed value?

Comment: Does "tags" not have a "maxspeed" string?

Comment: You're not looking at "tags", you're looking at the element that contains "tags"...

Comment: "JSONObject tags = (JSONObject) speedJSON.getJSONObject(i).get("tags");
                  String maxspeed = tags.getString("maxspeed");" Something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get maxspeed from the `element`, but it's not there. It is inside `tags` object in the `element`.

You need something like this

```
if (!element.isNull("tags")) {
    JSONObject tags = element.getJSONObject("tags");
    String maxspeed = tags.getString("maxspeed");
    txtSpeed.setText(maxspeed+" here");
} else {
    //Your error handling here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it working after some emulator problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
String maxspeed = element.getString("maxspeed");
```

to

```
String maxspeed = element.getJSONObject("tags").getString("maxspeed");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it working after some emulator problems